# Laravel 5 Fatal Error HtmlServiceProvider

Tags: forms, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.2 normally from composer,
already installed.

the first time I run php artisan server, there is no problem.
After create and modify some controller to add Html Form, I got an error when 
I want to run php artisan serve,

```
 D:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore>php artisan serve
    PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared() in D:\xampp\htdocs\bookstore\vendor\illuminate\html\HtmlServiceProvider.php on line 36


  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::bindShared()
```

How I can solve this one?

Comment: Can you post your code of your view and your composer.json file?

Comment: This is the path of the file, not the code

Comment: This is view in books/index.blade.php

https://jsfiddle.net/5fadtxeu/

Comment: and your composer.json file?

Comment: here is the composer.json file https://jsfiddle.net/kk2n10br/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `illuminate/html` component is no longer part of Laravel proper, and hasn't yet been updated to conform to 5.1 standards.

You need to remove:

```
'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider',
```

and

```
'Form'      => 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',
'Html'      => 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade',
```

form your `config/app.php`

then remove from your `composer.json` `illuminate/html` then add to your `composer.json`:

```
"laravelcollective/html": "5.*"
```

in `require` section

then `run composer install`